# jQuery - firing function on two separate events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my navigation works in two ways - by clicking arrows and by swiping (on mobiles).

My "click" function is as follows:

```
        $(this).children('.carousel-control').on('click', function() {
            config.containers.removeClass('fading');
            config.containers.removeClass('fadingback');

            if($(this).is('.left')) {

                $(this).parent().addClass('fading');
                config.mainCont.animate({
                    scrollLeft: $(this).parent().prev('article').offset().left
                }, 500);

            } else {

                $(this).parent().addClass('fadingback');
                config.mainCont.animate({
                    scrollLeft: $(this).parent().next('article').offset().left
                }, 500);

            }

            return false;
        })
```

Now, I don't know if I can avoid writing it one more time but using `swipe` instead of `on`. Is there a way to avoid this?

I tried writing separate functions, like this:

```
function goLeft() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('fading');
    config.mainCont.animate({
        scrollLeft: $(this).parent().prev('article').offset().left
    }, 500);
};

function goRight() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('fadingback');
    config.mainCont.animate({
        scrollLeft: $(this).parent().next('article').offset().left
    }, 500);

};
```

and running them like this:

```
        $(this).children('.carousel-control').on('click', function() {
            config.containers.removeClass('fading');
            config.containers.removeClass('fadingback');

            if($(this).is('.left')) {

                goLeft();

            } else {

                goRight();

            }

            return false;
        })
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you mean with "doesn't work" ? return error?

Comment: Simply runs "normally", fires the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that: you are using $(this) inside your function .try to pass it from your caller

try this:

```
$(this).children('.carousel-control').on('click', function() {
            config.containers.removeClass('fading');
            config.containers.removeClass('fadingback');

            if($(this).is('.left')) {

                goLeft($(this));

            } else {

                goRight($(this));

            }

            return false;
        })

function goLeft(here) {
    $(here).parent().addClass('fading');
    config.mainCont.animate({
        scrollLeft: $(here).parent().prev('article').offset().left
    }, 500);
};

function goRight(here) {
    $(here).parent().addClass('fadingback');
    config.mainCont.animate({
        scrollLeft: $(here).parent().next('article').offset().left
    }, 500);

};
```

Comment: You can't have an argument named `this`. Also, why are you jQuerifying twice?

Comment: I did something similar, but I still need to call `on` and `swipe` separately.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski you can't avoid that, since they're using two different conditions

Comment: @JanDvorak okay then, thanks for the info. Post it as your answer please ;)

Comment: @TomekBuszewski I would think you already knew that... I don't think this answer would be useful to future visitors